# What´s wrong with this template in Qt? QFile deleted constructor?

Tags: c++, qt, templates, methods, qfile

So, this is my template function. And I get the error massage "call to deleted constructor of 'QFile' ".
How can I fix this? Or can you tell me recommendation, how can I write this function as template in best way?

```
template <class T>     // T shall be the name of a class
void example(QVector<T> &vec, const QString &fp, std::function<void(QFile)> func) //func is a method from a class
{
    QFile f(fp);
    if(!f.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Append) )
    {
        qDebug() << "File error" << f.error();
    }
    else
    {
        QThread::currentThread();
        for(T &tw : vec)
        {
            //tw.func(f);     
            func(f).tw;      **//call to deleted constructor of 'QFile'**                   
        }
    }
    f.close();
}
```

func can be this for example:

```
void writeTeamData(QFile&);
void teamType::writeTeams(QFile &f)
{
    QTextStream out(&f);
    out.setCodec("UTF-16LE");
    out << teamId << "\t" << offsideTrap << "\t" << withoutBall << "\t" << formationId << "\t"
            << attack << "\t" << teamMentality << "\t" << attackTactic1 << "\t"
            << attackTactic2 << "\t" << defenseTactic1 << "\t" << defenseTactic2 << "\t" << captain << "\t"
            << penaltyTakerId << "\t" << kickTakerId << "\t" << leftCornerkickTakerId << "\t" << rightCornerkickTakerId << "\t"
            << numTransfersIn << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy a `QFile` as the copy constructor has been deleted.
Change the signature of `example` to take a `std::function<void(QFile&)> func` instead.